# How to automatically clone interface from package?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm using a package in my react-native app. I'm building my API and I want to use the same interface as the package does, ie, the package contains a interface:

```
export interface CandleStickDatasetConfig
    extends CommonDatasetConfig,
        BarLineScatterCandleBubbleConfig,
        LineScatterCandleRadarConfig {
    barSpace?: number | undefined;
    shadowWidth?: number | undefined;
    shadowColor?: Color | undefined;
    shadowColorSameAsCandle?: boolean | undefined;
    neutralColor?: Color | undefined;
    decreasingColor?: Color | undefined;
    decreasingPaintStyle?: CandleStickPaintStyle | undefined;
    increasingColor?: Color | undefined;
    increasingPaintStyle?: CandleStickPaintStyle | undefined;
}
```

As it can be seen, this interface extends lots of other interfaces, so if I want to use it in another project, I would need to create all of them manually in the backend as well, or install the package, but some other interfaces from this package relies on react-native interfaces, so this is not an option.

Is there a way to automatically clone the interface I want to use and generate a new interface based on everything that is extended from the `CandleStickDatasetConfig` interface?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can "clone" an interface with something like:

```
import type { CandleStickDatasetConfig } from 'some-module-here'

export interface MyClonedInterface extends CandleStickDatasetConfig {
  // optionally extends the interface here...
}
```

`import type` ensures that no runtime code is imported, just type information. That way any react native specific code does make it into the compiled application code.

However, that's not that different than just importing the type directly. If you really want to use this type without installing the package, then you'll have to manually copy the types from that package to some other place, but then there's no point in sharing them...

Comment: This way I'd have to install the package, and then it breaks because the package depends on react native, and I just want to use the interface in my API project